# Write TXT file with VBA - File is interrupted

Tags: excel, vba, file-io

I have a VBA macro that writes a txt file in "datevalue" format (that is, year tab month tab data) before running the X13 ARIMA SEATS.

It has always worked, but recently it works only some times. When I looked at the .txt file it generated before seasonally adjusting it, it was interrupted in the middle of a row. For 1998 until July 2018 it writes the file as it has always done, but than it stops in the middle of the decimal place.

This is the part of the code that writes the txt datevalue file. Ano and mes (year and month) are inputs from the beginning of the code.

```
Private Sub copyData(ByVal mes As Integer, ByVal ano As Integer, rng As Range)
    Dim sFileText As String
    Dim iFileNo As Integer
    Dim i, col As Double

    i = rng.Row
    col = rng.Column
    ficar = True
    iFileNo = FreeFile

    Open "P:\Macro\X12\Input\serie1.txt" For Output As #iFileNo

    'Writes the file with the time series
    While Cells(i, col) <> ""
        Print #iFileNo, ano & Chr(9) & mes & Chr(9) & Cells(i, col)
        If (mes + 1) Mod 12 > 0 Then mes = (mes + 1) Mod 12 Else mes = 12
        If mes = 1 Then ano = ano + 1
        i = i + 1
    Wend

    Close #iFileNo

End Sub
```

This is the head of the .txt file

```
1998    1   4641.272855
1998    2   3943.235604
1998    3   5167.087047
1998    4   4629.068494
1998    5   4736.139222
1998    6   4703.891762
1998    7   5394.787069
1998    8   4155.992635
1998    9   5741.168184
1998    10  5460.08048
```

This is the tail, where it stops working.

```
2018    4   13790.364479
2018    5   13259.844355
2018    6   14320.106493
2018    7   16101.08
```

My guess is that the file now it too long.

UPDATE!!
I added a MsgBox before Wend (as below) so the code would run slower (I keep pressing enter as it runs) and it worked. So I think it breaks the file-writing because it takes too long.

```
MsgBox ano & Chr(9) & mes & Chr(9) & Cells(i, col)
```

Comment: Probably at that last cell's value in the file, there is a special (unvisible) character included in the cell's value which is later read as CHR(26) End-Of-File-character (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file). Please try this: Remember that cell's value, delete it and insert it digit by digit by hand and run it again.

Comment: Does Excel or VBA terminate regularly or is there an error? What is the file-size of ’serie1.txt’? And how many rows are missing compared to the Excel sheet?

Comment: @Asger actually, my cells are all formulas. Do you think maybe that is the problem?

Comment: @hc_dev some times it terminates regularly and some times it just breaks my excel! I never get the error message... the file size is 6KB. There are 254 rows, and it writes until row 247.

Comment: Figures seem to be in normal ranges (254 rows should be written fast, file of 6KB should not cause trouble). What happens if you select another sheet or workbook for your macro, what if you move the starting-range? Will it always break at the same cell (in row 247)? _Point is: your VBA code looks correct :)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A follow up (if anyone ever face this problem):

I think the file was too long for my excel, and it some how it got overwhelmed. The solution was to limit the number of decimals before running the code. So I put a =ROUND(xxx, 2) on my excel file!

I hope it helps!